# is there support for Linux/Unix in minted?

Tags: minted

I'm trying to type up some notes that include some commands on a Linux course I'm taking so I thought of loadign `minted` in the preamble of my tex document. To my great surprise it seems there isn't any support for linux/unix language. I carefully scrolled through the output of

```
$ pygmentize -L lexers
```

but no linux is there. Any way to get around this problem? I'm on a Win7 OS with Texlive 2015, AUCTeX editor.

This gives error:

```
\begin{minted}{latex}
  sysadmin@localhost:~$ cat /etc/updatedb.conf
\end{minted}
```

Comment: Try `shell-session` instead of `latex`.

Comment: Not surprising, because there are not  such  "Linux/unix language" ?  The linux kernel is made with C, but a lot of Linux programs are made with ruby, perl, python, C++, etc., etc., etc. If you mean the shell (command-line interpreter) in Linux usually is bash,  but there are others as csh,  ksh or  tcsh.  You can see most of these  with  `pygmentize -L lexers`.

Comment: I resorted to simply write the commands in a different font -- `texttt{cd ./Documents/`

Answer (score 9):

This answer is just another repeat of the comments above.

The minted package does highlight shell languages.

It does not show a lot on your input, though, as you are not using any shell constructs, but a POSIX program.

As always, compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape <myFile>.tex`.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\paragraph{Your prompt command, not much highlighted}
\begin{minted}{shell-session}
sysadmin@localhost:~$ cat /etc/updatedb.conf
\end{minted}
\paragraph{An actual shell script}
\begin{minted}{shell}
for k in {1..5}
do 
    echo $k
done
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```