# Package for visualize Command Line Commands

Tags: packages

I have to write an Install guide. Therefore I have to explain the command line way.
Did anyone know a package for display Command Line?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378015/is-there-support-for-linux-unix-in-minted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the `listings` package for this. See the example below which defines two environments, one to typeset Ubuntu terminal (command line) commands and one to typeset Python shell sessions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Macro \lsteveryline{<tokens>} to prefix tokens to every line
\makeatletter
\def\lst@everyline{}
\lst@AddToHook{EveryLine}{\lst@everyline}
\newcommand\lsteveryline[1]{\renewcommand\lst@everyline{#1}}
\makeatother

\lstnewenvironment{ubuntu-terminal}[1][]{
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=bash,
    #1
  }%
  \lsteveryline{\$ }%
}{}

\lstnewenvironment{python-shell}[1][]{
  \lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    language=Python,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue!50!black},
    stringstyle=\color{green!50!black},
    showstringspaces=false,
    #1
  }%
  \lsteveryline{>>> }%
}{}

\begin{document}
  Ubuntu terminal example:
  \begin{ubuntu-terminal}[gobble=4]
    sudo apt-get install terminator
  \end{ubuntu-terminal}
  Python shell example:
  \begin{python-shell}[gobble=4]
    print("Hello, World!")
  \end{python-shell}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]